# RSA public key recovery from signatures

Tags: rsa, public-key, key-recovery

Is it possible (how) to recover public (512 bit long) RSA key from multiple signatures having corresponding plain texts. Padding is not randomized.
I need it to verify any future message comming from the same source.

Comment: That's an odd problem; are you really trying to verify that the signatures are from the same source, even if you don't know what that source is?

Comment: Well, the context is that those plain-text messages signed by an unknown private key are kind of electronic certificates signed by a central authority. Those certificates, extended to parties from a certain context, are used to sign electronic documents. I am one of those parties from that certain context so I have certificates that belong to me that I know are valid but I am unable to truly validate any electronic document from any other party since I can not validate it's certificate since the authority's public key is kept in secret even though it should have been published.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have two message-signature pairs, $(m_1, s_1), (m_2, s_2)$, where $s_i = m_i^d \bmod n$. Suppose we also know the public exponent $e$—it is usually $65537$, $3$, $5$, $17$, or some similar small integer. Then we know that $m_i = s_i^e \bmod n$, or in other words $s_i^e = k_in + m_i$ and it follows that $\gcd(s_1^e - m_1, s_2^e - m_2) = \gcd(k_1, k_2)n$, where $\gcd(k_1, k_2)$ is expected to be small.

Comment: Note that, while Samuel's answer is correct, and shows that an attacker can rederive the public key (at least for small $e$), that might not what you want to do routinely.  For $e=65537$, this implies computing the $gcd$ of two bignums each 4 million bytes long -- that might take a while...

Comment: On a more practical note: before doing this calculation you must first calculate $m_i$ by performing the right padding mechanism.

Comment: I am able to understand this answer after some thought, but the fact that it skips over the encoding of $m$ and doesn't explain how to get to the final solution may confuse readers that just get the signature values and know how to code (+ hopefully some basic math skills).

Comment: @poncho: e is most probably equal 3. How long while are we talking about using a standard modern PC: days, weeks, years, centuries? Is this problem parallelizable?

Comment: With $e=3$ it should be nearly instantaneous---the $\gcd$ of two $1536$-bit numbers is pretty cheap. $e = 65537$ takes around 30 seconds in my machine.

Comment: @SamuelNeves I have succesfully recovered public keys with e=3 in no time at all but I fail to recover this particular public key at e=3... GCD comes very small so I guess e is not 3 in this case (nor 5 or 17) and for GCD with e=65537 my code takes more than 30 seconds... just preparing s1^65537 and s2^65537 takes over 30 seconds... I will leave it calculating for a few hours... What do you use for your calculations? I use python's long numbers.

Comment: There is also a remote possibility that non standard $m_i$ calculation method is used :-(

Comment: Still calculating GCD for $s^e_1 - m_1$ and $s^e_2 - m_2$, each number has around 33 million bits, every 100 iterations of gcd algorithm both numbers lose around 100 bits... estimated completion time on my machine is around two days...

Comment: Vanilla Python will likely be too slow here. Instead, try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) or, if you do not want a gigantic package, use [gmpy](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) to use GMP for the arithmetic. It will be much faster than Python's native quadratic algorithms.

Comment: @SamuelNeves **I am speechless...** like for real man... seeing yesterday how long it takes with python to calculate gcd for my numbers I wrote a small ctypes wrapper for openssl's gcd function and it still was eating at the CPU without a pause for minutes (didn't wait)... and then using your advise to look at gmpy I rewrote my code to use it... **3 lines** were changed, 2 that prepare those big numbers and a call to gcd... I cliked execute and **12 seconds** later I have got the result! The python naive version is still calculating, eating bits away, still 19000000 to go and several hours.

Comment: Last update: the plain python version just terminated it's work and took 77357.91 seconds to recover the public key I was searching for, versus 12 seconds taken by gmpy2 version. Later I will publish the code on GitHub so people can check it out if anyone is interested.

Comment: Yep, just using calculations on a scripting language without acceleration is going to be dog slow. C# and Java should be faster, especially since they will rely on native implementations and / or HW accelerations to perform the calculations - and some Python implementations may as well (although the Marshalling to / from Python structures may add some overhead). For this kind of calculation a manually optimized C + assembly function may still give you the best results, regardless of the existence of optimizing compilers and such.