# In RSA signing find n from e and many pairs of m and c

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

When signing using RSA with $e = 65537$ and many pairs of m and c,
where
$$c^e \bmod (n)=m$$
is there a way to find n (n is 2048 bits)?

I planned on computing $ c^e-m $ and then treating those as a basis for a lattice.
But $c^e$ was too large.

Comment: Duplicate of https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26188

Comment: The answer provided by @poncho worked well. Also, moving from Python to SageMath improved the speed and made this doable on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to find n (n is 2048 bits)?

Yes, if you assume deterministic padding (which is sometimes used for signatures, which appears to be the case you're considering)

You're on the right track by considering $c^e - m$ (which will be a multiple of $n$); given that we have several, what we can do is take two, and compute:

$$\gcd( c^e-n, c'^e-m' )$$

This will be $n$ (multiplied by an integer with a high probability of being small; that's easy to scrap off); that's your answer.

The values we're taking the GCD of are about $2^{27}$ bits in length - using the standard binary or Euclidean algorithms would probably take rather longer than we would prefer to wait.  However, [Lehmer's GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_GCD_algorithm) should bring it into a range that's not intolerable...